# How can I access the elements separated by comma in xml tags?

Tags: python, xml, object-detection, yolo, labelimg

I need to store the elements separated by comma in xml tags

For example, these x and y coordinates:

```
<points>
    <point>558.000000,790.000000</point>
    <point>530.000000,829.000000</point>
    <point>567.000000,855.000000</point>
    <point>595.000000,815.000000</point>
    <point>558.000000,790.000000</point>
</points>
```

I tried something like this

```
x1, y1 = ((item.getElementsByTagName('points')[0]).getElementsByTagName('point')[0]).firstChild.data
```

But got the following error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Comment: You are assigning a string to 2 variables.  Add a `.split(',')` to convert it into a list to unpack. 

However, note that the unpacking will fail if there are 0 or more than 1 comma in the string

Comment: Can you include the code before your snippet so we can have a "minimal reproducible" example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently work on accessing the XML tags and I prefer `xml.dom.minidom` library of python for this use.

The code for your above-mentioned XML tags in the question is:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

name = "<points><point>558.000000,790.000000</point><point>530.000000,829.000000</point><point>567.000000," \
       "855.000000</point><point>595.000000,815.000000</point><point>558.000000,790.000000</point></points> "
point = []
xml_loaded = minidom.parseString(name)
Points_Node = xml_loaded.getElementsByTagName("points")
for Main_Node in range(len(Points_Node)):
    Point_Child = Points_Node[Main_Node].getElementsByTagName("point")

for Child_Node in range(len(Point_Child)):
    point.append((Point_Child[Child_Node].firstChild.nodeValue).split(","))

print(point)
```

The output for above-mentioned code is split with x and y coordinates and stored in an array as you requested in the question.
The output can be seen below:

```
[['558.000000', '790.000000'], ['530.000000', '829.000000'], ['567.000000', '855.000000'], ['595.000000', '815.000000'], ['558.000000', '790.000000']]
```

Hope this help, please let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<points>
    <point>558.000000,790.000000</point>
    <point>530.000000,829.000000</point>
    <point>567.000000,855.000000</point>
    <point>595.000000,815.000000</point>
    <point>558.000000,790.000000</point>
</points>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for element in tree:
    x,y = element.text.split(",")
    print(x, y)
```